# How to effectively use a callback with PF('myDataTable').filter() in Primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

I'm running Primefaces 5.1, and running into a situation where I need to hide a table until after the filter has been applied in the javascript.  I was hoping to just set the css on the table to `visibility:hidden;`, and to then run the following in the javascript:

```
PF('myDataTable').filter();
$('.myDataTableCssClass').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Unfortunately, the table is set to `visibility:visible;` before the filter is applied.  I need to somehow set that CSS *after* the filter has completed, but I can't get any kind of callback method to work.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the primefaces extensions [pe:javascript](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/clientBehaviours/javascriptBehaviourAnother.jsf) with the filter event and the oncomplete attribute where in the oncomplete you do the visible.  In the onstart you can do the hiding.

So

```
<pe: javascript event="filter" oncomplete=" $('.myDataTableCssClass').css('visibility'">
```

Comment: You don't need PF extensions, [<p:ajax event="filter" />](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/b2c095571eb81ac9ff6dd3180630e7f6c4fad115/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L978) would do it.

Comment: Ok, in earlier pf versions these failed for me when not having a listener on them.  If this now works **without** a server roundtrip that is new to me and good that it works

Comment: This was perfect.  For the record, the <p:ajax event="filter" was sufficient.